# SteamWriter doesn't want to create file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write my logs to a file, so that whenever my application should crash the logs are still saved in the logfile. However the StreamWriter doesn't let me, I've tried every path posibility, but everytime I try to test this it throws me this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
```

The path however should be fine, as shown in the console output:

```
StartLogging=True Trying to write to C:\Users\Tom\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\xxx\yyy\bin\Debug\logs\06-11-13_11:51:37.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I can't see why this doesn't work...

SaveLog function:

```
    public void SaveLog(bool startLogging = false)
    {
        DateTime startTime = LogManager.StartTime;
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        string logPath = appPath.Replace("file:\\", "") + "\\logs\\";
        string logFile = startTime.ToString("MM-dd-yy_HH:mm:ss") + ".log";
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(logPath, logFile);

        if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("StartLogging={0} Trying to write to {1}", startLogging, fullPath);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, !startLogging))
        {
            writer.Write("[{0}][{1}] ", Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), Level.ToString());
            writer.Write(Message);
            writer.WriteLine(" ({0} - {1})", Method, Location);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Paths in windows cannot contain the colon (:) character.

Comment: Paths can. Directory and file names can't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can use a colon (`:`) in your filename.

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177506

> A filename cannot contain any of the following characters:
>
> ```
> \ / : * ? " < > |
> ```

Comment: Correct. It's used for the separator between drive and path.

Comment: Yeah you're completely right! How I didn't see that remains a mystery, but I'm glad it's solved. Thanks for the quick answer!